# Mongodb Upgrade on Aws Bean stalk

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to upgrade mongodb version, there is already installed mongodb having version 2.6.4 and i want to update version 3.2.4. I put file named mongo.conf under .ebextenstions, but it is not working. mongodb is not going to update. So there is no data , so no worry about any backup , simply want to update.

**Mongo.conf file**

```
files: 
  "/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo":
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      [mongodb-org-3.0]
      name=MongoDB Repository
      baseurl=http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/
      gpgcheck=0
      enabled=1
  "/opt/mongos.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      net:
        port: 27017
      operationProfiling: {}
      processManagement:
        fork: "true"
      sharding:
        configDB: mongo-cfg1.internal.company.com:27019,mongo-cfg2.internal.company.com:27019,mongo-cfg3.internal.company.com:27019
      systemLog:
        destination: file
        path: /var/log/mongos.log
container_commands:
  01_install_mongo:
    command: yum install -y mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.2
    ignoreErrors: true
  02_start_mongos:
    command: "/usr/bin/mongos -f /opt/mongos.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Please help me, what i am doing wrong here, i am new to aws beanstalk. I unable to find any documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/ :

> To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.2, you must be running
>   a 3.0-series release.

You **must** upgrade your 2.6 replica set to 3.0 before trying to upgrade to 3.2.